# getting System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

While Initializing a native android page again

Error:

> Unable to activate instance of type

I use this code

```
    public MySecondPageRenderer() : base()
    {

    }

    public MySecondPageRenderer(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
    {
        if (Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
    }
```

but now it is showing the Null reference exception with  Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException` and `NullReferenceException` are not the same thing. Which one are you getting? And on what line?

Comment: Initially i was getting System.NotSuppotedException which was showing  no constructor found

Comment: after adding the following code it is showing NullReferenceException while executing the parameterized Constructor. The value of second parameter is Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer

Comment: Normally, the constructor is not necessary for custom renderer as the base renderer already inherited from `java.lang.object`. Could you please post detailed codes of this renderer?